# JSTL <fmt:formatData> time zone problem

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

If I'm in Europe, Germany, and I use:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="BOTH" timeZone="America/Los_Angeles"/>
```

the date and time are formatted always as

17-05-2011 1.32.10

and not as in English format with first month and then day.

Only the time zone is corrected.

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `pattern` also, overriding `timezone` won't change the output format

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="BOTH" timeZone="America/Los_Angeles" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"/>
```

Comment: So if this tag is not able to convert, automatically, to the local formatting of a date I think it's not very useful. Strange that in the specification is not said!

Comment: does locale holds the date pattern ? and also there can be custom locale also. so how you will handle it in tag?

Comment: If I specify a pattern attribute then I want to use it else the container should use that is concerning the timeZone attribute.

Comment: Ok I found the solution I MUST specify the locale to use before every action: <fmt:setLocale value="en_US" /> and thus I MUST NOT ovveride pattern!!!

Comment: Yes it will does but force the programmer to know the locale formatting pattern.

Comment: _Yes it will does but force the programmer to know the locale formatting pattern_ didn't get you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an explicit pattern and always want to force the use of a single locale, you can try including the following in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale</param-name>
    <param-value>en_US</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You shouldn't have to use `<fmt:setLocale>` with this approach. You can also get and set configuration data through the `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` class (for example, in a listener, filter or servlet).